# Disable all bindings on Tab if not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a tabcontrol with 2 tabitems on a UserControl.

Depending on the license I decide which one to hide.

The problem is I have on both these tabitems the same controls binding to the same properties. The thing is they are overwriting each other resulting in unexpected results. So now I want it to work like when the TabItem is set on Visibility Hidden then disable the bindings on that tabitem.

Anyone any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: How is the overwriting happening? Something must be writing the data back from the invisible UI to the viewmodel.

Comment: @ChrisF From the question, I'm assuming the OP is using the same binding source for both sets of controls. When a value is updated in a control, the value is updated automatically in the binding source so, when the other tab is activated it shows the updated value rather than the original value.

Comment: @Kevin - I assumed that it was the data in the view model getting overwritten rather than the data in the view. If it's the latter then everything is working as designed as the whole point of binding to the same data is that the UI updates.

Comment: @ChrisF - I agree.